# Connecting to an Oracle database from Xampp Lite USB?

Tags: database, oracle, xampp

I have Xampp Lite installed on a USB drive and it works very well, however, I've run in to an issue connecting to Oracle databases.

Is it possible to connect to an Oracle database without installing anything on the client computer?  Another way to put this... can I add something to the USB drive that will enable me to connect to an Oracle db from my PHP code?  I don't have the ability to install anything on the client computer, only the USB drive.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [oracle instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html) will do the job

Described as

> Instant Client allows you to run your applications without installing
>   the standard Oracle client or having an ORACLE_HOME. OCI, OCCI, Pro*C,
>   ODBC, and JDBC applications work without modification, while using
>   significantly less disk space than before. Even SQL*Plus can be used
>   with Instant Client. No recompile, no hassle.
>
> Oracle Database drivers for popular languages and environments
>   including Node.js, Python and PHP can use Instant Client to connect to
>   local or remote databases.

Further details on the installation are found [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/10893_3371561_2/Instant-Client-in-Oracle-10g.htm).  The usual Oracle Home, Path and TNSNAMES must be set.  You do need to know what the drive letter your USB will mapped to.